# Powershell: Joining two ouputs

Tags: powershell

I am running into an issue when attempting to create a 'subquery.' I'm fairly new to Powershell, but have some experience with SQL, hence the issue i am running to. So i am querying for printing jobs in a file server and i am trying to associate the user name back to AD in order to get the department for each user. The end goal is to retrieve data to analyze printer usage per department in order to properly allocate funds. the script i have below outputs the user name for each print job:

```
$location4='\\roch-fs02\c$\Powershell_Printing_Logs\users.txt'
$pattern = '"(.+)","Document (.+), (.+) owned by (.+) on (.+) was printed on (.+) through port (.+). Size in bytes: (.+). Pages printed: ([^&])'
Select-String -Pattern $pattern -Path $location|ForEach {
new-object psobject -Property @{
TimeCreated=$_.matches[0].Groups[1]
DocumentNumber=$_.Matches[0].Groups[2]
Document=$_.Matches[0].Groups[3]
User=$_.Matches[0].Groups[4]
Machine=$_.Matches[0].Groups[5]
Printer=$_.Matches[0].Groups[6]
Port=$_.Matches[0].Groups[7]
Size=$_.Matches[0].Groups[8]
Pages=$_.Matches[0].Groups[9]
}
}|where {$_.printer -notmatch 'ne' }|
select user |
out-file $location4
```

This piece of code outputs the department of each user:

```
$users=Get-Content $location4 |select -Skip 3 
$department=for ($i=0 ;$i -le $users.Length – 20; $i++)
{Get-qADUser   $users[$i]|select department,samaccountname}
```

Is there a way to get those two outputs in the same .txt file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the users from the print log are samaccountnames, I'd build a hash table of users and departments:

```
$Department = @{}
$users=Get-Content $location4 |select -Skip 3 
$department=for ($i=0 ;$i -le $users.Length – 20; $i++)
{Get-qADUser   $users[$i]|select department,samaccountname} |
 foreach {$Department[$_.samaccountname] = $_.department}
```

Then use that to insert a Department property in your objects from the Department hash table, using the user/samaccountname:

```
$location4='\\roch-fs02\c$\Powershell_Printing_Logs\users.txt'
$pattern = '"(.+)","Document (.+), (.+) owned by (.+) on (.+) was printed on (.+) through port (.+). Size in bytes: (.+). Pages printed: ([^&])'
Select-String -Pattern $pattern -Path $location|ForEach {
new-object psobject -Property @{
TimeCreated=$_.matches[0].Groups[1]
DocumentNumber=$_.Matches[0].Groups[2]
Document=$_.Matches[0].Groups[3]
User=$_.Matches[0].Groups[4]
Department = $Department[$_.Matches[0].Groups[4]]
Machine=$_.Matches[0].Groups[5]
Printer=$_.Matches[0].Groups[6]
Port=$_.Matches[0].Groups[7]
Size=$_.Matches[0].Groups[8]
Pages=$_.Matches[0].Groups[9]
}
}|where {$_.printer -notmatch 'ne' }|
select user |
out-file $location4
```